# Полупрозрачный фон виджета в QT

Tags: qt, c++

Необходимо сделать фон виджета `QLabel` полупрозрачным. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?
`opacity` использовать не получается, т.к. оно может использоваться только в всплывающих окнах.

Comment: ты че, хочешь типа "дырку" сделать в форме? То есть прозрачную дырку в непрозрачной форме? Или?

Comment: Есть основная форма  QMainWindow. Она имеет фоновую картинку. На форму добавляется виджет QLabel c некоторым текстом. Поскольку он становится дочерним, в нем по умолчанию фоном становится картинка родителя. А это мне не нужно. Нужно чтобы фон в QLabel был белого цвета, но полупрозрачный, чтобы немного видна была фоновая картинки основной формы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Надо расширить класс QLabel и в новом классе переопределить метод paintEvent, вставив туда примерно такой код

```
QPainter paint; 
paint.begin (this);
paint.setBrush (QBrush (QColor (255, 255, 255, 180)));
paint.setPen (Qt::NoPen);
paint.drawRect (0, 0, width(), height());   
paint.end();
```

В QColor последнее значение - значение альфа-канала, которое и определяет прозрачность. Меняется от 0 (полностью прозрачное) до 255.

Comment: Согласен, что надо делать не средствами окна (setWindowOpacity), а средствами рисования (в paintEvent). Добавлю только что можно использовать свойства QPixmap, QBitmap и можно будет делать прозрачными участки картинки в зависимости от цвета.

Answer (score 6):

Не согласен с предыдущим оратором. Делать так можно, конечно, но лучше использовать стайлшиты. Например такой текст стайлшита для полупрозрачной кнопки:

```
QPushButton {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 0); // цвет текста желтый
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 90) // зеленый полупрозрачный фон rgba
}
```